# GPU Not rendering in Cycles after a GPU swap

Tags: rendering, gpu

Got a brand new GPU (RTX 4080) to replace a RTX 2070 Super.
Thought Blender would render faster but it simply does not work at all.
When I switch to GPU rendering (on a defaut cube scene) everything stays gray, not a single path trace is launched.

I tried:
-Cuda (Card recognized in the options)
-Optix (Card recognized in the options)
-Install latest (and previous) drivers, both Studio and Game ready version, none work.
-Check / uncheck denoising
-Viewport and Render Window (both doesn't work)
-Several blender version (from 2.9 - 3.3 to 3.4 to even 3.5 Alpha)

What work:
-Eevee
-CPU rendering

The Gpu works well as expected on video games and other softwares such as DaVinci Resolve / fusion compositing.

Comment: You might want to run DDU and fresh install the newest drivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED:

Download the drivers through [GeForce Experience](https://www.nvidia.com/en-gb/geforce/geforce-experience/download/).

Comment: Hi @GeoffreyK! You can click the tick next to this (your own) answer, to mark it as accepted. Then others will see it's cleared up.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to deal with the same problem after updating my recent RTX 4080 driver.
I tried **waiting through the Cycles "kernel initialization" (a few minutes)** in a default Blender scene. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You should try different graphics Driver which matches your new card.

Sometimes older version of drivers may not give you fast result.